# Failed to resolve "System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" reference from "System, Version=4.0.0.0"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I am getting MT2002 error after moving to VS2022 when setting Xamarin.iOS project to ad-hoc to generate .ipa file. I am not using System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter and not referencing it. Linking is set to SDK only. Anyone know how to fix it?

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.7.3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084 
ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.7.273.65229
NuGet Package Manager   6.7.0  
VisualStudio.Mac   1.0    
Xamarin   17.7.0.216 (d17-7@133ddef)
Xamarin.Android SDK   13.2.1.2 (d17-5/a8a26c7) 
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   16.4.0.15 (8c3876d5e)
```

Here are Logs from that error message:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(223,3): error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" reference from "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
6>  --- inner exception (TaskId:389)
6>  Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter (TaskId:389)
6>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/builds/mono-ios-sdk-destdir/ios-sources/external/linker/src/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:2287  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x00055] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/builds/mono-ios-sdk-destdir/ios-sources/external/linker/src/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:1072  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.MobileMarkStep.MarkType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x00001] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/MobileMarkStep.cs:51  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.CoreMarkStep.MarkType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x00130] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/CoreMarkStep.cs:187  (TaskId:389)
6>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchMarkStep.MarkType (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x00001] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/MonoTouch.Tuner/MonoTouchMarkStep.cs:84  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField (Mono.Cecil.FieldDefinition field) [0x0001e] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/builds/mono-ios-sdk-destdir/ios-sources/external/linker/src/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:1018  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireType (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x000dc] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/builds/mono-ios-sdk-destdir/ios-sources/external/linker/src/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:181  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkEntireAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00043] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/builds/mono-ios-sdk-destdir/ios-sources/external/linker/src/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:896  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x0004a] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/builds/mono-ios-sdk-destdir/ios-sources/external/linker/src/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:87  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize () [0x00016] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/builds/mono-ios-sdk-destdir/ios-sources/external/linker/src/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:77  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/builds/mono-ios-sdk-destdir/ios-sources/external/linker/src/linker/Linker.Steps/MarkStep.cs:69  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Xamarin.Linker.Steps.CoreMarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00017] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/CoreMarkStep.cs:32  (TaskId:389)
6>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchMarkStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0001d] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/linker/MonoTouch.Tuner/MonoTouchMarkStep.cs:36  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context, Mono.Linker.Steps.IStep step) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/builds/mono-ios-sdk-destdir/ios-sources/external/linker/src/linker/Linker/Pipeline.cs:134  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/builds/mono-ios-sdk-destdir/ios-sources/external/linker/src/linker/Linker/Pipeline.cs:126  (TaskId:389)
6>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.Linker.Process (Mono.Linker.Pipeline pipeline, MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchLinkContext context) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/common/Tuning.cs:31  (TaskId:389)
6>  --- (TaskId:389)
6>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.Linker.Process (Mono.Linker.Pipeline pipeline, MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchLinkContext context) [0x00020] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/common/Tuning.cs:36  (TaskId:389)
6>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.Linker.Process (MonoTouch.Tuner.LinkerOptions options, MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchLinkContext& context, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition]& assemblies) [0x000de] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Tuning.mtouch.cs:61  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Target.LinkAssemblies (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition]& assemblies, System.String output_dir, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] sharedCodeTargets) [0x00257] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Target.mtouch.cs:514  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Target.ManagedLink () [0x00719] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Target.mtouch.cs:670  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Target.ProcessAssemblies () [0x000c2] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Target.mtouch.cs:873  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Application.ProcessAssemblies () [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Application.mtouch.cs:945  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Application.BuildManaged () [0x00001] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Application.mtouch.cs:360  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Application+<>c.<BuildAll>b__43_1 (Xamarin.Bundler.Application v) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Application.mtouch.cs:308  (TaskId:389)
6>    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].ForEach (System.Action`1[T] action) [0x0001e] in <bab7d1a00376483b944db50cdc31e41d>:0  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Application.BuildAll () [0x00050] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Application.mtouch.cs:308  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Driver.Main2 (System.String[] args) [0x00413] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/mtouch.cs:675  (TaskId:389)
6>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/tools/common/Driver.cs:52  (TaskId:389)
6>  The command exited with code 1. (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Trying to get a Build Connection... (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Sending Request Xamarin.Messaging.GetActiveAgentsMessage to topic xma/agents (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Received Response of Xamarin.Messaging.GetActiveAgentsMessage to topic build1488416004khag/+/xma/agents (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Sending Request Xamarin.Messaging.GetActiveAgentsMessage to topic xma/agents (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Received Response of Xamarin.Messaging.GetActiveAgentsMessage to topic build1488416004khag/+/xma/agents (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: The Build Connection 'Xamarin.Messaging.Build.Client.BuildConnection.14884' is active and ready to use (TaskId:389)
6>  MTouch: 2023-08-29T16:35:50.9650371-05:00 - Task execution failed. Disconnecting from the Remote Server... (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Starting disconnection... (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Closing the underlying Messaging connection... (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Closing the underlying Messaging connection... (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Closing the underlying MQTT connection... (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: The underlying MQTT connection has been closed. (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Disposing Messaging connection references... (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: The underlying Messaging connection has been closed (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Disposing SSH Messaging connection references... (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Starting SSH disconnection... (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Stopped local forwarded port to 55808 (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Disconnected SSH client (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Disconnected SCP client (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: The underlying Messaging connection has been closed (TaskId:389)
6>  [xma][info]: Disposing Messaging service references... (TaskId:389)
6>  MTouch: 2023-08-29T16:35:51.1994945-05:00 - Finished (TaskId:389)
6>Done executing task "MTouch" -- FAILED. (TaskId:389)
6>Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "MobileApp.UI.iOS.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:325)
```

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7098

Answer (score 0):

According to Hans Passant's comment, as an answer:

> I am getting MT2002 error after moving to VS2022 when setting Xamarin.iOS project to ad-hoc to generate .ipa file. I am not using System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter and not referencing it. Linking is set to SDK only. Anyone know how to fix it?

You can refer to the solution in the link: [Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Diagnostics...](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7098).

Comment: I am still unable to find what is causing the issue. I looked at the link you provided.